# How was applied the formula of linear regression in this case?

Tags: regression

I am following a course in Coursera about Introduction to Statistics and I got lost in the part of the explanation of the linear regression. I know is a simple subject, but I do not get it how the instructor applies the linear regression formula to solve an example case.

According to the slides the instructor says that the regression line is obtained by the following formula:

$$\hat{y}=a+bx    $$ given that:
$b=r\frac{s_{y}}{s_{x}}$ and $a=\bar{y}-b\bar{x}$

So I could plug the values of a and b into the equation and obtain the following:
$$\hat{y}=\bar{y}-b\bar{x}+r\frac{s_{y}}{s_{x}}x$$

The example the instructor mentions is the following:

The case is to predict the final exam score of a student who scored 41 in the midterm, the data available is: $\overline{midterm}=49.5,\overline{final}=69.1,s_{mid}=10.2,s_{final}=11.8,r=0.67$

so the instructor then says that the score of 41 is below the $\overline{midterm}$ in 8.5 points, we can call this the $difmidterm$. Then he calculates the following: $$\frac{diffmidterm}{s_{mid}}=\frac{8.5}{10.2}=0.83$$

I suppose that the last term could be considered like the standard deviation of that score, am I right?

Then he plugs all the values in an equation that it is not mentioned, but I suppose is derived from the equation of the regression line; so far I think the equation he uses is:

$$\hat{y}=\overline{final}-r*s_{mid}*s_{final}$$
$$=69.1-0.67*0.83*11.8=62.5$$

The minus sign is because the value of 8.5 is below the mean and the final answer would be 62.5 as our prediction. However, I do not see how this equation $\hat{y}=\overline{final}-r*s_{mid}*s_{final}$ relates to $\hat{y}=\bar{y}-b\bar{x}+r\frac{s_{y}}{s_{x}}x$.

What detail am I missing in this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $\widehat{y}=\overline{\text{final}}-rs_\mathrm{mid}s_\mathrm{final}$ is wrong. The correct equation should be
\begin{eqnarray*}
\widehat{y}&=&\overline{\mathrm{final}}-r\frac{\overline{\mathrm{mid}}-x_\mathrm{new}}{s_\mathrm{mid}}s_\mathrm{final}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $x_\mathrm{new}$ is the new midterm score of the student. This equation is equivalent to $\widehat{y}=a+bx_\mathrm{new}$ where $b=r\frac{s_\mathrm{final}}{s_\mathrm{mid}}$ and $a=\overline{\text{final}}-b\times\overline{\text{mid}}$. Consider the above equation,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\widehat{y}&=&\overline{\mathrm{final}}-r\frac{\overline{\mathrm{mid}}-x_\mathrm{new}}{s_\mathrm{mid}}s_\mathrm{final}\\
&=&\overline{\text{final}}-r\frac{s_\mathrm{final}}{s_\mathrm{mid}}(\overline{\text{mid}}-x_\mathrm{new})\\
&=& \underbrace{\overline{\text{final}}-r\frac{s_\mathrm{final}}{s_\mathrm{mid}}\overline{\text{mid}}}_{a}+\underbrace{r\frac{s_\mathrm{final}}{s_\mathrm{mid}}}_{b}x_\mathrm{new}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks @ccy for pointing out my mistake